# Unity error at the export. How can i fix it?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, export

In Unity is the following error how can I fix it because I want to export my program:
FileNotFoundException: Failed to find $C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.6f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\GradleTemplates\mainTemplate.gradle
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.GetTemplate (System.String toolsPath, System.String fileName) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is a problem with the indicated path.
In such cases, perhaps it is better to uninstall the android export package and re-download it.
To do this go to the file: Files / Unity / Hub / Editor / 2021.3.6f1 / Editor / Data / modules.json.
In this file, find the section with the camo id equal to "android" and set the selected field to false.
Do the same for the sections with the ids "android-sdk-ndk-tools", "android-sdk-platform-tools", "android-sdk-build-tools" android-sdk-platforms-29 "," android -sdk-platforms-30 "," android-ndk "," android-open-jdk ". Basically, all those are related to Android.
Then in the Files / Unity / Hub / Editor / 2021.3.6f1 / Editor / Data / PlaybackEngines folder, delete the Android player.
Restart Unity and Unity Hub and from Unity Hub, you will be able to re-download the Android modules.
For prevention make a copy of the Files / Unity / Hub / Editor / 2021.3.6f1 / Editor / Data folder and maybe even the project, if something goes wrong ...
If the problem continues, it probably means there is some setting change in the build settings.

Answer (score 0):

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Unity editor 2021.3.6f1 then the Android modules separately and got same error.

I ended up copying the entire missing tool directory from Unity 2021.3.5f1 and then my build worked.

C:\Program Files\Unity\2021.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools

to

C:\Program Files\Unity\2021.3.6f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools

Answer (score 0):

first delete .gradle folder in C:\Users\username

Again build

Comment: if .gradle don't deleted , window is restart , and first deleted folder before open unity

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this problem now with my first Unity.

I got this error on Build and run to Android.

GradleTemplates was found in C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.6f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\cmdline-tools\2.1.

So I copied everything to C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.6f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools and it worked.